# I'm aware of a user that has previously admitted to downvoting with a script but the votes haven't been retracted. What do I do?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

Double edit: the flag has been marked as helpful on August the 10th but nothing seems to have happened with the downvotes? I know it's just -2 rep for each downvote but it'd be great to see it returned :P

Edit: I've since flagged the user but the flag has been sat pending for some time. Hopefully it will be reviewed at some point <s>instead of ageing away</s> instead of sitting there pending for ages (thanks Shadow Wizard for the correction).

---

I've discovered a user that has admitted that they have used a script to downvote multiple answers on questions. Off this site they have posted a screenshot of the proof of the downvotes, and on the website where they posted it they have mocked people for calling them out.

[image: cropped screenshot of serial downvoting]

I've cropped out the profile name for privacy.

I looked at some of the users on the answers that were downvoted and the votes have yet to be retracted.

Is there a way to report users like this? Their profile also seems to show some kind of annoyance against the moderation on the SE network.

Comment: Flag one of the user's posts with a custom moderator flag and explain the problem in detail or use the contact link in the footer of this page.

Comment: Important to note that voting on all answers to a question (which is what your screenshot looks like) isn’t serial voting. Serial voting is repeatedly voting for the *same user*.

Comment: Such users should be manually suspended, the auto detection can't and shouldn't play a role. (As it won't help, they'll just repeat their disruptive behavior)

Comment: Regarding edit: custom flag never age away, it will just sit in the mod queue forever. I have pending flag here on MSE for over a year for example. It can't expire, just be ignored. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ah cool I didn't know that. That makes me wonder how big the queue is for custom flags... Ah well. :/

Comment: Depends what site? Also, size doesn't matter... I guess that when mods don't know how to handle a flag they just leave it to sit in the queue.

Comment: You should also crop out the entry with the bounty. It's easy to identify them with that info.

Comment: Good point. I'll crop it out when I get the chance to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The serial voting detection script won't pick this up; it's designed to find targeted voting on specific *users*, not answers to specific questions (like what happened on June 16).

As @RobertLongson says, flag one of the user's posts with a custom moderator flag and explain the problem in detail. This isn't something regular ♦ moderators can do something about other than passing it on to the community team, but they'd like to know who did this so that they can keep an eye on them. Because, as @Sonic notes in the comments, this happened on Meta Stack Exchange, you can also use the [contact](/contact) link in the footer of this page; the ♦ moderators on this site are the same people as those monitoring the inbox of the contact form.

Comment: Thanks. I'll get them flagged (and edit my question accordingly!)

Comment: This is on Meta Stack Exchange, so an employee will process the flag anyway.

Comment: Sometimes every single answer to a question does deserve to be downvoted. How do we distinguish such cases?

Comment: That's left to the discretion of the community team? Also, if I'd really think all answers to a question deserved a downvote, I'd not share such a screenshot as in this question.