# Witnessing suspicious down-voting activity on other people's posts on the same stack. (No one can read that fast unless they're gifted)

Tags: discussion

I witnessed 4 posts on a stack-feed get down-voted sequentially and in a quick amount of time.

I've been observing this phenomenon for months. Albeit this is the first time I refresh a page in under 60 seconds four posts got downvoted.

**I know for a fact that it's extremely unlikely for someone to read that fast!**

The downvotes are indiscriminate when it comes to an OP's best efforts or the quality level of content.

After giving some consideration that it could be coincidental, should I send screenshots the next time I see it?

Comment: Some posts could be very long and with signs of good effort and they still get downvoted in rows of 4 or so.

Comment: Links to the questions you're talking about would be helpful if a CM were to investigate.

Comment: Why do you assume those downvotes come from one user?

Comment: @Tom Because there's been a [history](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=7638558#7638558) of [cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312408/377214) where people have indiscriminately downvoted content.

Comment: Travis, A few users and myself have replied to a few people to explain that the answer to the comment they wrote is contained in the first sentence/paragraph/etc., or that they have posted a few comments and that our lengthy post is less than a minute old. The same can happen with up or downvotes. There's a few people whom think that's helpful, and a few with extra time available to address the issue. To meet with the terms of the CoC any replies require extra time to be carefully, and with thoughtfulness and kindness, crafted to address the issue; while 'right to ask' or vote is *protected*.

Comment: Well, it often takes only a 250ms glance at a title to assess that a question is almost certain to be one of a set of mega-dupe homework questions that are posted continually.  Opening the question and a quick scan to be sure takes a couple seconds, downvoting and closing another, and the question is handled.

Comment: _"in under 60 seconds four posts got downvoted. I know for a fact that it's extremely unlikely for someone to read that fast!"_ → I know for a fact that 15 seconds is plenty of time to read an average-length question, decide if it's worth up/down voting it, and do so. It definitely took me less than that to read the title of yours in the Questions list, open it in a new tab and read the rest before deciding to comment. I am not saying there's nothing sketchy going on; just that you should not think so only because somebody reads questions faster than you are used to.

Comment: Could be, could not be. Voting fraud surely exists not only outside of this network. The question would be where to send the screenshots to? The moderation would need some sort of mailbox to receive them.